# Rest Server with Z1 Websense

Tags: rest, server, contiki

Hi Stackover'followers :). I'm very much new to Stackoverflow. Let me put forward a question I have regarding Instant Contiki. Anybody who has idea on Instant Contiki, zolertia motes, REST Server, is welcomed to resolve it out.

I could successfully work on the two different motes by considering '**z1-websense.c**' and  '**rest-server-example.c**'.

> But I want to get the result of '**z1-websense.c**' which is the
>   temperature, by executing the '**rest-server-example.c**'.

So, regarding this, there is something to be done in the '**rest-server-example.c**' code, may be by calling a `function` for **z1-websense.c**, which I'm unable to crack it.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to clarify the question.

Comment: thanks for your response. i actually have a vague idea, that is the reason i could explain it briefly and simply.

Comment: @kfx : I thank you for your interest in knowing more about what I wanted to do. Basically in (https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/er-rest-example) , we can access, for example either the battery, leds, button or radio etc by executing the **er-example.server.c**.  By accessing the server address, we get the required http response. But, I have to create a similar rest service for the temperature (https://github.com/iRamprasad/rest-temperature-sensor). For which i face a lot of problems with errors. I would request you for any kinda help from your side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the rest-engine app on Contiki let's you set up resources and handlers for methods called on them.

So, if I understood, you want to tweak the resource GET handlers in [er-example-server](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/er-rest-example/er-example-server.c) to taylor onto the z1 mote, in particular a resource for the battery sensor and a resource for the temperature one.

If you take a look at [z1-websense.c](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/5a26d25647df2aa8daec2e2afa0712f5f06d5f68/examples/z1/ipv6/z1-websense/z1-websense.c) the values are retrieved and simply scaled (lines 66-79).

```
static int
get_battery(void)
{
  return battery_sensor.value(0);
}

static int
get_temp(void)
{
  return temperature_sensor.value(0);
}

static float get_mybatt(void){ return (float) ((get_battery()*2.500*2)/4096);}
static float get_mytemp(void){ return (float) (((get_temp()*2.500)/4096)-0.986)*282;}
```

Take that code and inject it into the battery and temperature resources you can find here[enter link description here](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/er-rest-example/resources) and you are done.

So in the end you will have something like

file ***res-battery.c***, line 60
float battery = ( battery_sensor.value(0) *2.500*2) /4096 ;

You should do similarly for the temperature and you are done.

Remember to deactivate all sensors/resources you are not interested in, since they would take precious memory.

I cannot test it right now, but this should work.

Comment: Hey Mr Michele, thanks a lot for your amazing response. And I'm sorry that I respond too late as I was busy with my exams and I just now I saw this answer. Well, let me say that your idea seems to be perfect. I'll implement it and check it out. I'll let you what I get then. Once again, I'm really thankful for your interest in sorting out this query.